# VSTS Load Testing against Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cdn

I wanted to confirm the capabilities of Azure CDN, so I set up a VSTS load test against my static web page with other static resources. I chose 6000 users for 1 minute. I also chose to use "automatically provisioned agents" and as a result VSTS said it used 17 agent cores, though the logs only show 5 agents.

Any immediately concerning is the Avg. Response Time of 4.6 sec! I went to the diagnostic tab and found a slew of OutOfMemoryExceptions as well as high CPU warnings on the agents.[[image]

Since I'm not controlling the servers, I can only assume that the load testing tool has some issues with scale, though I would also have assumed it would be good at that. A load testing tool should not fail under load.

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how I can run a successful load test, as described.

Comment: Seems can't reproduce this issue. What's the result with a new load test?

Comment: Tried again last night. Same result. Can you try against my site? http://www.maze-o.com

Answer (score 1):

The error message you see could be caused by the high resource(CPU/Memory) usage on the agent. You can increase the "Agent Count(Total Cores)" and then try to run the test again. I created a load testing with basic request to test your site with "Agent Count(Total Cores)" set to 40 (6000 users for 1 minute), didn't see the OutOfMemory exception anymore and the average response time is 404.1 ms.
[image]

And for the 17 agent cores only show 5 agents, it is expected behavior. Refer to the table below for details:
[image]

Comment: I'm using "automatically provisioned agents" and I don't see an option to set the Agent Count. It looks like that option exists only if using "self-provisioned agents".

Comment: @DanFriedman It seems that you are uploading the webtest from VSTS web portal directly to generate the load testing. And it is not supported to set the agent core in VSTS web portal for Visual Studio Test. I would recommend you to create load test in Visual Studio and use Visual Studio to upload the test to VSTS. In this way, you will be able to configure more settings.

Comment: I am struggling with this performance issue as well with web-based URL tests. I don't have access to Visual Studio Enterprise to specify number of cores directly. If I understand @EddieChen-MSFT approach, Eddie still has 6000 v-users but they are spread out over 40 cores, instead OP's 5 cores. This has a direct effect on the average response times.